# issue with column name 'type' in rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a columns named 'type' in  one of my tables. When I try to access it like group.type, I got the following error:

```
super: no superclass method `type' for #<Group:0x000000035eaf30>
```

However, when I try to rename the column using a migration, I get the following error

```
No such column: groups.type (migration failed)
```

I tried to rename the column directly in the mysql db, using a query, but that doesn't work either.

```
mysql> alter table groups change type group_type int(11);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'type' in 'groups'
```

Please help.

Comment: found the answer i was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000703/cant-figure-out-activerecordsubclassnotfound-in-registriesedit

Answer (score 18):

The error comes from the single table inheritance feature that comes with ActiveRecord. Just tell it to use a different column than `type`:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.inheritance_column = nil

  #...
end
```

With that, you don't have to rename the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think `type` is [ReservedWords in Ruby on Rails](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords).
So try to access like this:

```
groups.[type]
```

Comment: @RahulSingh  Please Show your query.

Comment: i guess you meant group[:type]

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find you have to surround the word type with a backtick (**`**). 'type' is a reserved word I think and that's what will be causing your error.

I'm on my phone right now so I can't paste the character you need but it's in the top left of most standard keyboards.

Comment: I know the character you mean. Thanks. Is There a way I can get away without renaming the column?

Comment: You shouldn't have to rename the column.  I'm not familiar with Ruby on Rails so I'm not sure if my suggestion will help!! Just to be sure the character I mean is this one `