# User models and roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What’s the best way to implement roles? Essentially what I want is one User model. But I want two different type of users. 1) regular user which they can Buy products. 2) second user is a seller. This user can add and delete products.

How can I add a seller to user? I would like the buyer and seller to have the same devise views. Can you give an example please?

Currently I have a user model(devise) and a products model.

Comment: Can a user also be both, buyer and seller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way, but here an example how what can be done. Using enum :

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable,
         authentication_keys: [:login], password_length: 4..32, unlock_strategy: :time

  enum available_roles: {buyer: 100, seller: 101}

  def buyer?
    has_role?(User.available_roles[:buyer])
  end

  def seller?
    has_role?(User.available_roles[:seller])
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.include?(role)
  end

end
```

For using permissions (like only a seller can add and delete products) you can use the libary cancancan https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: If you're using `enum` for this (which is a nice approach here), you'll get access to `user.buyer?` and `user.seller?` automatically ([docs here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)), meaning you don't need to create them manually @Xero.

Comment: I really like this way. However, the way i want it is by default a user when a user signs up they are automatically a buyer. They can purchase any type of product. I the admin would have to create an account for buyers because i would want to verify their business and etc. So the buyer would be on the client side and the seller would be in the internal side of the application. Could your method still work for this?

Comment: @Xero so how would i access this in the view? Would it be <% if @user.is_buyer? %>

Comment: @Djjhjuser10735674 yes excactly. By the way, I renamed the method "buyer?" and "seller?" are more clean name

Answer (score 2):

You can use cancancan gem. And add a column seller(boolean) to users table.

Then on ability.rb

```
if user.present?
  can :read, Product
end

if user.seller?
 can :manage, Product, user_id: user.id     
end
```

This, assuming a product belongs to a user, will allow sellers to create/edit/delete their products(if products are common for all sellers you can remove the part `user_id: user.id`).

While all the rest (buyers) can see all products. If they buy probably they can create an order or whatever you will call it..

Answer (score 0):

You can add column `user_type` to user. You can set default to `buyer` or you can provide type select list to `create/update` form of user.

Further you can use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem to define permissions for them

Comment: Don't use type for a db column it will conflict. Use user_type instead.

Comment: @Catmal Are you sure? I had used it in app (rails-4), did not bother. Can you explain little?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984893/issue-with-column-name-type-in-rails-3 but i got that error on rails 5 too.

Comment: @Catmal Yes I know this as it is just valid case only in case of `single table inheritance (STI)`. Still I updated answer to avoid future rare possibility what you said!

Comment: Ok I probably need to read more about it. I didn't pay attention to it when error occured :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is having different models and tables for customers and sellers as these are logically different entities. CustomerModel will interact with your client applications and SellerModel will interact with your internal application. This is a better way as far as I think.

Still if you wish to have them in single table I would suggest adding type column in the users table and then using the principles of Single table inheritance. The benefit you have with STI is that you can make your code much more modular and add methods specific to customers and sellers in their respective models which would in turn inherit from UserModel.

Here is a link for for single table inheritance which might be of some help: [Single table inheritance explained](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/)

For access control you can use the Pundit gem. Here is a [github](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) link for the same.