# Rails: Renaming column in migration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple migration which fails: The database is not affected, it still contains the old column name after migrating.

```
class RenameTypeToLicenseTypeInLicenses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    rename_column :licenses, :type, :license_type
  end
end
```

Renaming `type` to `license_type` is necessary because of this error:

```
The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'creative commons'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite License.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

This is the output of `rails db:migrate`

```
igrating to RenameTypeToLicenseTypeInLicenses (20210422110849)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
== 20210422110849 RenameTypeToLicenseTypeInLicenses: migrating ================
== 20210422110849 RenameTypeToLicenseTypeInLicenses: migrated (0.0000s) =======

  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20210422110849"]]
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.4ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2195010657070977375)
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
```

How can I rename the `type` column?

*edit*:
As there's only little data in the table, I tried another approach:

```
remove_column :licenses, :type, :string
add_column :licenses, :license_type, :string
```

It doesn't work either. Output is

```
[NAME COLLISION] `type` is a reserved key in LicenseResource.
   (0.7ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(2195010657070977375);
   (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Migrating to ChangeTypeToLicenseTypeFromLicenses (20210422122638)
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
== 20210422122638 ChangeTypeToLicenseTypeFromLicenses: migrating ==============
== 20210422122638 ChangeTypeToLicenseTypeFromLicenses: migrated (0.0000s) =====

  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20210422122638"]]
   (4.6ms)  COMMIT
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.6ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2195010657070977375)
   (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
```

Comment: You can keep the type column by adding following in your target model
`self.inheritance_column = nil` or  `self.inheritance_column = 'some_other_type_name'`. By this way AR won’t refer type column to STI(single-table inheritance)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, but I'd prefer to change the column name. Using `type` still generates a warning from the JSONAPI::Resources gem which we use.

Comment: is your existing type column contains some data?

Comment: Yes, there's data (strings) in it.

Comment: As per your recent edit on the post. On running `remove_column` migration, is `type` column still present in your db? (visible in `schema.rb` file) if it is, is there any error on the terminal while running the migration?

Comment: I don't think I have that file, only `structure.sql`. However, the `type` column is still there. I pasted the output of `rails db:migrate` for this second approach to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231462/discussion-between-farhad-ajaz-and-pida).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I wonder if ActiveRecord's migration code might be trying its best to keep `type` intact, on the assumption that it's currently being used for single table inheritance; it's oblivious to the fact you want to change it because it currently *isn't*

There may be an idiomatic Rails way of telling the migration that what you're doing is fine, but to be honest I'd be tempted to drop down to the SQL level, thus bypassing Rails' erroneous protection:

```rb
class RenameTypeToLicenseTypeInLicenses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    execute <<~SQL
      ALTER TABLE licenses RENAME COLUMN type TO license_type;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<~SQL
      ALTER TABLE licenses RENAME COLUMN license_type TO type;
    SQL
  end
end
```

As you're not using migration commands, you have to provide separate up/down code for both directions of the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer should help you: [issue with column name 'type' in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984893/issue-with-column-name-type-in-rails-3)

`type` is one of those reserved words we shouldn't use. Check other reserved words here: https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/32446/reserved-word-list

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything you write was mentioned before, though: Your link was to a question, but the first answer contained the same advice as Farhad Ajaz' comment to my question. The cause of my problem was mentioned in the question itself.