# Rails ActiveRecord querying the wrong model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my controller in index action:

```
    @keys = Quran::Ayah.fetch_ayahs(params[:surah], range.first, range.last).map{|k| k.ayah_key}

    # @cardinalities = Quran::Surah.first
    @cardinalities = Content::Resource.fetch_cardinality(params[:quran])
```

When I leave these two, I get this in console:

```
Quran::Ayah Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "quran"."ayah".* FROM "quran"."ayah"  WHERE (quran.ayah.surah_id = '1' AND quran.ayah.ayah_num >= '1' AND quran.ayah.ayah_num <= '5')  ORDER BY quran.ayah.surah_id, quran.ayah.ayah_num
Content::Resource
  Content::Resource Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "quran"."resource".* FROM "quran"."resource" JOIN content.resource_api_version  using ( resource_id )
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "quran.resource" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "quran"."resource".* FROM "quran"."resource" JOIN con...
                                         ^
: SELECT "quran"."resource".* FROM "quran"."resource" JOIN content.resource_api_version  using ( resource_id )
  Rendered bucket/ayat/index.jbuilder (2.3ms)
```

When I comment the `@keys` line, it works fine:

```
Content::Resource Load (3.7ms)  SELECT "content"."resource".* FROM "content"."resource" JOIN content.resource_api_version  using ( resource_id )
```

No idea why this is happening? Why is it querying for `quran.resource` when the model is not that!

Models:

```
class Content::Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Content

    self.table_name = 'resource'
    self.primary_key = 'resource_id'

    belongs_to :author, class_name: 'Content::Author'
    belongs_to :source, class_name: 'Content::Source'
    belongs_to :language, class_name: 'I18n::Language', foreign_key: 'language_code'

    # maybe make the block below a polymorphic class, accessible via 'content' or something
    # dunno wth polymorphic relationships really are, so maybe not -- fancy crap not worth a brain cell
    has_many :_image, class_name: 'Quran::Image', foreign_key: 'resource_id'
    has_many :_text, class_name: 'Quran::Text', foreign_key: 'resource_id'
    has_many :_word_font, class_name: 'Quran::WordFont', foreign_key: 'resource_id'
    has_many :_tafsir, class_name: 'Content::Tafsir', foreign_key: 'resource_id'
    has_many :_translation, class_name: 'Content::Translation', foreign_key: 'resource_id'
    has_many :_transliteration, class_name: 'Content::Transliteration', foreign_key: 'resource_id'
    has_one  :_resource_api_version, class_name: 'Content::ResourceAPIVersion', foreign_key: 'resource_id'


    def self.fetch_cardinality(params_quran)
        Rails.logger.info Content::Resource
        @results = Content::Resource
        .joins('JOIN content.resource_api_version  using ( resource_id )')
        # .select([:sub_type, :cardinality_type, :language_code, :slug, :is_available, :description, :name].map{ |term| "content.resource.#{term}" }.join(', '))
        # .where("content.resource.is_available = 't' AND content.resource.type = 'quran'")
        # .where("content.resource_api_version.v2_is_enabled = 't' ")
        # .where("content.resource.resource_id = ?", params_quran)
        return @results
    end
end


class Quran::Ayah < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Quran

    self.table_name = 'ayah'
    self.primary_key = 'ayah_key'

    belongs_to :surah, class_name: 'Quran::Surah'

    has_many :words, class_name: 'Quran::Word', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'

    has_many :tokens, class_name: 'Quran::Token', through: :words
    has_many :stems, class_name:  'Quran::Stem',  through: :words
    has_many :lemmas, class_name: 'Quran::Lemma', through: :words
    has_many :roots, class_name:  'Quran::Root',  through: :words

    has_many :_tafsir_ayah, class_name: 'Content::TafsirAyah', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'

    has_many :audio, class_name: 'Audio::File', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'
    has_many :texts, class_name: 'Quran::Text', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'
    has_many :images, class_name: 'Quran::Image', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'
    has_many :glyphs, class_name: 'Quran::WordFont', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'
    has_many :tafsirs, class_name: 'Content::Tafsir', through: :_tafsir_ayah
    has_many :translations, class_name: 'Content::Translation', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'
    has_many :transliterations, class_name: 'Content::Transliteration', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'


    def self.fetch_ayahs(surah_id, from, to)
        self
        .where("quran.ayah.surah_id = ? AND quran.ayah.ayah_num >= ? AND quran.ayah.ayah_num <= ?", surah_id, from, to)
        .order("quran.ayah.surah_id, quran.ayah.ayah_num")
    end
end
```

UPDATE:

I occassionally get this error if it helps:

> The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'content'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Content::Resource.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.

Comment: shouldn't be `quran` as plurals as per Rails conventions ?

Comment: where do you see that?

Comment: Inside the method `fetch_ayahs` of class `Quran::Ayah`, you had defined.. scroll below..

Comment: Quran is the namespace for the model which corresponds to Postgresql schema.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think it has something to do with me having a column 'type' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000703/cant-figure-out-activerecordsubclassnotfound-in-registriesedit but I don't know how to work around that

Comment: May be.. Just wait.. I am not expert in Rails.. May be @muistooshort will help you out..

Comment: Run a migration to rename `type`... I used to have this problem too. It solved after renaming column.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy if you have a column named `type` rename it to something else has `type` is a reserved word in rails for STI see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions

Comment: Yeah, `type` is special... rename it to something else  `<something>_kind` often works well.